# How to check whether Session Attribute is successfully set?

Tags: jsp, session, servlets, session-management

I have multiple servlets and jsp pages (around 100) and I want to do session management for these using `HttpSession`. Is it necessary to check for `HttpSession.getAttribute()` in each of the servlets and jsp  pages after setting the attribute for `HttpSession`.

Is there any convenient way so that I don't have to check `HttpSession.getAttribute()` in each of the servlets and jsp files?

Comment: What do you mean by check and validate ? If an attribute is in session, **you** have put it there so you can safely assume it is valid ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want to achieve can be done using **Servlet Filters**. For more info you can check this:- 
http://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/servlet-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to repeat checking session in every servlet (and jsp) you can create a base servlet class having its `service()` method overridden with a code in the beginning like `HttpSession.getAttribute()` and then call an abstract `doService()` which you must implement in all the servlets and latter must extend from the base servlet. For JSPs, it is bit tricky (as extending from a JSP is complex, may not be even practical), but you can have a JSP fragment with this code which you can `<@include ...>` in all your JSPs at the beginning. Using some template framework for JSP will make it easier. Hope, this gives you some idea on how to proceed further.